# Fail vs Error in automated tests

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-management

**Do you guys separate fails and errors in your automated tests report?**

- fail - assert error
- error - all code errors (except from asserts)

In my opinion **we should**. Lets say we have such testcase scenario:

1. login -> logged in
2. Create contact (example) -> contact created

If we'd have 2 automated tests for these...:

- I test

  1. login
  2. **ASSERT** if logged in
- II test

  1. login
  2. create contact
  3. **ASSERT** if contact created

... and login will be bugged, we could simply filter test results with **fails** only and find out that login failed (because we have assert on that) by ignoring other **ERROR** types (we could have 20 of them) that occurred due to that login fail)

**What's your approach/experience?**

Comment: Are you talking about application errors or automation code errors itself?

Comment: Also if it is an application error,it should be trapped in one of the assertions,as the expected states of objects will be changed somehow as an impact of the error.

Comment: Example: home Page title assertion will be failed if on login there is an runtime error displayed on the page instead of Home page.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Im talking about automation code errors itself

Answer (score 2):

We started to separate fails and other errors in our reports from the beginning and see that welcomed by readers of the reports.

The **fails** are an outcome of a test that is somewhat expected. When seeing a **pass** or **fail** the reviewer will know that the basic logic has worked. When encountering an *error* it's a clear sign that the test itself has failed to operate as expected.

Users later requested that automatic screenshot logging also differs between the two ([logScreenshotOnFail](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#testSettings.logScreenshotOnFail-property) and [logScreenshotOnError](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#testSettings.logScreenshotOnError-property)) which I would count as a proof that the differentiation makes sense and is wanted.

Comment: This answer also fits my topic, but I chose @Alexey R. as it has better argumentation, sorry mate :/

Answer (score 2):

Strict methodologies allow automated test case only to be **Passed** or to be **Failed**.

There could be negative test cases, where the application returns errors, but if this is properly expected, the test will be Passed as you expect an error.

So if you tend to filter out some fails, most probably you don't have proper assertions defined.

If you have a data-driven test, you should include an "expect" for each dataset and define such assertion which compares expected and real result.

Comment: @Shinigamiyuu this attitude will lead you directly to the failing, buggy software and test results which are unreliable and not relevant.

Comment: +1. Exactly. It makes no difference what statement caused the test to fail. @Shinigamiyuu - Go ahead and disagree, it just shown your lack of experience.

Comment: Maybe we got eachother wrong.
I want to filter FAILS as priority number 1 just to see which asserts failed (first thing to take a look, because this error will be more readable as its expected to be handled).
Obviously I won't be ignoring ERROR reports, I'll just put it as second priority while reading the test results.

What do you guys think? @PeterMasiar

Answer (score 2):

We separate assertion errors and code errors. The latter often means we missed some important logic to cover with assertions. So we tend not to have any exceptions (or code errors).

Thus in our practice the code errors (exceptions) usually appear in the case of some really **exceptional** cases like database unavailability or so, which are not related to business logic of the application under test and which we cannot impact or control.